# error message "Incorrect syntax near '.'" when creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to perform Insert and Update operations in a single stored procedure. Please help.  However, I keep getting this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertUpdate, Line 39 [Batch Start Line 623]
> Incorrect syntax near '.'

Here is the sample query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUpdate]
    @Action VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Action = 'INSERT'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO t1 (t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3)
            SELECT t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
            FROM t1 
            INNER JOIN t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
            WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL
    END

    IF @Action = 'UPDATE'
    BEGIN
        SET t1.col2 = CAST(t2.col2 as nvarchar(6)),
            t1.col3 = CAST(t2.col3 as tinyint)
        FROM t1 
        INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
    END
END;
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Is this SQLServer or some other db platform? Exactly which line is line 39? The INSERT SQL does not make sense. Joining on null is not possible and then you filter for only records where t1.col1 is null. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1447/join-sql-server-tables-where-columns-include-null-values/

Comment: it was a typo. It has been edited.  I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Same comment applies even tho filter is on t2.col1. Maybe you want NOT IS NULL?

Comment: The `INSERT` should list the columns - but **without** any prefixes! `INSERT INTO t1 (col1, col2, col3)` ....

Answer (score 1):

This logic is not allowed:

```
    SET t1.col2 = CAST(t2.col2 as nvarchar(6)),
        t1.col3 = CAST(t2.col3 as tinyint)
    FROM t1 inner join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

Presumably, you intend:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.col2 = CAST(t2.col2 as nvarchar(6)),
        t1.col3 = CAST(t2.col3 as tinyint)
    FROM t1 inner join
         t2 
         on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```